# Insert query is trying to insert null values but values should not be null

Tags: sql-server

Below is the query I am running. My problem seems to be in the INSERT Statement below. What I have is a list of FeatureKeys and I traverse through this list one by one using ROW_NUMBER() so as to input each individual FeatureKey at a time. The problem is that the first few FeatureKeys are input correctly no problem but towards the end of the list it says I am trying to insert NULL values to the FeatureKey column. As an example I have a list of 4 FeatureKeys I then try to input each FeatureKey one by one individually the first 2 get inserted correctly that last says I am trying to insert NULL values to the FeatureKey column. I have tried printing the FeatureKey values to the console at different parts of the loop and it is fine it prints out all the values one by one. It is only when I try to execute the INSERT statement that for whatever reason the FeatureKey variable is NULL.

```
DECLARE @Count INT, @RowFeature INT,  @MaxParts INT, @TotalNewFeatures INT, @InspectionKey INT, @FeatureKey INT 
SET @InspectionKey =
    (SELECT Inspection_Key FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Inspection WHERE Op_Key = 562634);  
SET @TotalNewFeatures = 
    (SELECT COUNT(Features.Feature_Key)
    FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Features
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT *
            FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Position 
            WHERE Features.Feature_Key = Position.Feature_Key
                AND Inspection_Key_FK =
                        (SELECT Inspection.Inspection_Key
                        FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Inspection
                        WHERE Op_Key = 562634))
        AND Part_Number_FK =
                (SELECT Part_Number
                FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Operation
                WHERE Op_Key = 562634)
        AND Operation_Number_FK =
                (SELECT Operation_Number
                FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Operation
                WHERE Op_Key = 562634));  

SET @Count = 0;  
SET @RowFeature = 0  
SET @MaxParts = 13 

WHILE(@RowFeature < @TotalNewFeatures)  
BEGIN  
    SET @RowFeature = @RowFeature + 1;  

    SET @FeatureKey =
            (SELECT Feature_Key
            FROM (
                    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Features.Feature_Key ASC) AS RowNumber, Features.Feature_Key
                    FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Features  
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                            SELECT *
                            FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Position 
                            WHERE Features.Feature_Key = Position.Feature_Key
                                AND Inspection_Key_FK = 
                                        (SELECT Inspection.Inspection_Key
                                        FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Inspection 
                                        WHERE Op_Key = 562634))
                        AND Part_Number_FK =
                                (SELECT Part_Number
                                FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Operation
                                WHERE Op_Key = 562634)
                        AND Operation_Number_FK =
                                (SELECT Operation_Number
                                FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Operation
                                WHERE Op_Key = 562634)) AS foo
            WHERE RowNumber = @RowFeature); 

    WHILE(@Count < @MaxParts)  
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Position(Inspection_Key_FK, Piece_ID, Feature_Key)
        VALUES(@InspectionKey, @Count + 1, @FeatureKey)  
        SET @Count = @Count + 1  
    END  

    SET @Count = 0  
END
```

Below is my database diagram. There a WinForms program that a user enters an OpKey and a LotSize. OpKey pertains to a specific Part Number and Operation Number pair and multiple OpKey's can have the same Part and Operation Number. A user can add Features to a Part and Operation Number pair(NOT AN OPKEY) that way 2 different or more OpKey's can use the same Features without having to add Features to each OpKey. What I am trying to do here is Insert the Features for each part that the user wants to inspect which is also the LotSize. As an example, a user adds 3 Features to a combonation of PartNumber = 386022 and OperationNumber = 150. There are about 7 different OpKeys with this combonation. We'll use two of them. User punches in OpKey = 26266 with a LotSize = 10. Therefore this query creates 10 parts with 3 Features associated to each part. If I then punch in OpKey = 468753 and LotSize = 6, which is associate with the same Part and Operation Number, this query will insert 6 parts each with those same 3 Features. Now this query will also detect if any new features have been added after the fact and add those accordingly. So if user added a new Feature to the same Part and Operation number combo above when the user goes to punch in OpKey = 26266 the user can no longer choose a lotsize because it has already been created and will add the new Feature to each part in that inspection. So essentially it is just adding creating parts with the necessary features to be inspected to the Position table.

[DataBaseDiagramImage][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/svbgJ.png

Comment: This looks like an awfully complex query that could be done with a single set-based query. Perhaps you could provide what your tables look like and what result you're expecting and it would be easier to help you achieve what you want, rather than fixing a query that uses while loops (most likely) unnecessarily.

Comment: Proof of issue - In the last `WHILE` loop, replace the `INSERT INTO ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Position` statement with: `SELECT @InspectionKey, @Count + 1, @FeatureKey`, and see if any NULLs are output.  Also, place your `SET @Count = @Count + 1` statement before the `INSERT` to avoid having to add 1 to the `@Count` variable in the `VALUES` statement.

Comment: @LaughingVergil I am not seeing any NULLs it's all coming out correct

Comment: @LaughingVergil When I added the insert the SELECT query gave me NULL values in the FeatureKey

Comment: I started debugging it and somehow the big query where I set the FeatureKey skips every other Feature. So if there are 3 features it does the first and last and if there are 4 features it skips the first does the second skips the 3rd and does the 4th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

`WHERE RowNumber = @RowFeature`

You are adding rows to one of the tables that you are querying against that is used to exclude items from the information returned. You are also incrementing the @RowFeature value. The combination is working like this:

- *Read first feature (@RowFeature = 1)*
- *Add that item to the `Position` table*
- *Read next feature (@RowFeature = 2)*

  - *Because of the addition of the first feature to the `Position` table, the first feature is not returned when reading the next feature*
  - ***This means that the second feature is in RowNumber 1, and the third feature is in RowNumber 2***
- *Add the item with RowNumber 2 (Feature 3) to the `Position` table*
- *Repeat until done*

Given this structure, the solution would be to replace the `WHERE RowNumber = @RowFeature` comparison with `WHERE RowNumber = 1`

However, a better way of handling this would be to make this code more set based, instead of processing the data row-by-agonizing-row (RBAR). This will be easier if we create a small numbers table, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE Nums(num int primary key clustered)
INSERT INTO Nums(num)
SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.number) AS N
FROM master..spt_values t1 
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
```

This is used in your case to insert all `@maxParts` rows in one command. 
Something like this should work:

```
WITH foo as (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Features.Feature_Key ASC) AS RowNumber, 
        Features.Feature_Key
    FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Features  
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Position 
        WHERE Features.Feature_Key = Position.Feature_Key
            AND Inspection_Key_FK = (
                SELECT Inspection.Inspection_Key
                FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Inspection 
                WHERE Op_Key = 562634
                )
        )
        AND Part_Number_FK = (
            SELECT Part_Number
            FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Operation
            WHERE Op_Key = 562634
        )
        AND Operation_Number_FK = (
            SELECT Operation_Number
            FROM ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Operation
            WHERE Op_Key = 562634
        )
    ) 
INSERT INTO ATI_FeatureInspection.dbo.Position(Inspection_Key_FK, Piece_ID, Feature_Key)
SELECT @InspectionKey, Nums(num), foo.Feature_Key, 
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN Nums 
WHERE num <= @maxParts
```